# Dependency Violation when changing/deleting a resource in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, dependencies, terraform

I am facing an issue when deploy services to AWS via `Terraform`. The error I got is:

```
module.elasticsearch.aws_security_group.es: Still destroying... [id=sg-039f33d9b29a38c46, 9m39s elapsed]
module.elasticsearch.aws_security_group.es: Still destroying... [id=sg-039f33d9b29a38c46, 9m49s elapsed]
module.elasticsearch.aws_security_group.es: Still destroying... [id=sg-039f33d9b29a38c46, 9m59s elapsed]

Error: Error deleting security group: DependencyViolation: resource sg-039f33d9b29a38c46 has a dependent object
    status code: 400, request id: cd20a8e3-231f-444f-8479-b0575a98b390
```

It tries to delete a security group but found out there is a dependency object which stop it deleting it. I checked on AWS console the security group has an associate network interface which I don't have permission to delete. I found below changes on `terraform plan`:

```
~ name                   = "SecuritySearchElasticSearchtest" -> "SecuritySearchElasticSearch" # forces replacement
```

It tries to rename a security group during deployment.

I wonder why Terraform tries to redeploy it. Why not just use the existing resources? Can I force `Terraform` to not replace?

Comment: Can you change Group Name of (any) security group using AWS web UI?

Comment: I can only change display name not group name

Comment: Well, that answers your question: terraform is trying to recreate the resource because it can't rename it (and it is not terraform limitation, but AWS's)

Comment: But why does it want to rename it? Why not just use it?

Comment: That is difficult to say without knowing the current state and looking into your template. Maybe you simply changed the name in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to remove that SG from state by making command like

`terraform state rm module.elasticsearch.aws_security_group.es`

and then you can try to import that resource by making command

`terraform import module.elasticsearch.aws_security_group.es <security_group_id>`

please also keep in mind that in your terraform code name of security group should be `SecuritySearchElasticSearchtest` if you want terraform to avoid destroying that SG

Answer (score 2):

First Let's explain the problem you're dealing with

**The problem**: You're trying to apply some change on a resource in terraform though this resource is associated and connected to another resources. In this case, aws security group id reference is mapped and connected to another security groups and therefore  a `DependencyViolation` error is shown.

**For example:**

```
sg_a ( ingress: x, y, z       | outgress:all ) 
sg_b ( ingress: a, b, c, sg_a | outgress:all )
```

When `sg_a` is being removed the reference inbound still exists on `sg_b` and dependent on it. You applying your change and getting timeout message like:

````
...
module.some_module.aws_security_group: Still destroying... [id=sg-a, 10m elapsed]
module.some_module.aws_security_group: Still destroying... [id=sg-a, 13m elapsed]
module.some_module.aws_security_group: Still destroying... [id=sg-a, 14m elapsed]
module.some_module.aws_security_group: Still destroying... [id=sg-a, 15m elapsed]
 
Error: Error deleting security group: DependencyViolation: resource sg-a has a dependent object
status code: 400, request id: abc-123-zxc-567```
````

According to the [reference](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group) the dependency violation timeout comes after 15 minutes.

> delete - (Default 15m) How long to retry on DependencyViolation errors
> during security group deletion from lingering ENIs left by certain AWS
> services such as Elastic Load Balancing. NOTE: Lambda ENIs can take up
> to 45 minutes to delete, which is not affected by changing this
> customizable timeout (in version 2.31.0 and later of the Terraform AWS
> Provider) unless it is increased above 45 minutes.

**Solution**: The best way dealing with this violation dependency is refreshing the external resources using and depends on this dependency (in our example `sg_b` should not use `sg_a` , this ingress should be removed, afterwards applying your changes on terraform again and `sg_a` will be deleted.

in our **example** (remove `sg_a` ingress reference from `sg_b` security group) :

```
sg_a ( ingress: x, y, z | outgress:all ) 
sg_b ( ingress: a, b, c | outgress:all )
```

Now you can run `terraform apply`:

```
sg_b ( ingress: a, b, c | outgress:all )
```

Comment: It's quite baffling that the user has to "deal" with this dependency violation. So much for thinking Terraform is a infrastructure management tool-- at this point, it just defines infrastructure and is only viable if one doesn't change anything after the initial launch.